# Responsive webpage for small devices not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my web page responsive using bootstrap.
I want to remove the biggest image when the screen size is below `767 px`.
I want the content image and the content-title to come side-byside in mobile devices and the main-list to take up complete raw. But it is not happening right now.
The size of images used is: `content image- 250X250, featured image: 570X570, small images: 260X170`

I'm not able to set the size of the 2 small images for small screen devices.

```
<body>

<div class="container header-container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar5">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo image"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar5" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">24X7 Customer Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

</div>




    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 content-image">
                <img src="images/content.png" class="img-responsive" alt="content-image">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 content-title">
                    <h3>First Title here</h3>
                    <h2>Sub title here</h2>
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
                 <ul class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 main-list">
                        <li>ab jj jj jjh j hj jhj j hjhj h vgcfcgjv cggjbkjjjbhjbjbjbjbb</li>
                        <li>ab jj jj jjh j hj jhj j hjhj h vgcfcgjv cggjbkjjjbhjbjbjbjbb</li>
                        <li>ab jj jj jjh j hj jhj j hjhj h vgcfcgjv cggjbkjjjbhjbjbjbjbb</li>
                        <li>ab jj jj jjh j hj jhj j hjhj h vgcfcgjv cggjbkjjjbhjbjbjbjbb</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="row">

                <img class="col-md-6 small-image1 img-responsive" src="images/image1.png">
                <img class="col-md-6 small-image2 img-responsive" src="images/image2.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 featured-image">
                <img src="images/featured image.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
         <!-- end row-->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="courseHeading">Choose the State-Approved Course That Fits You Best</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 courses">
                    <h5>ABCDEFGHig</h5>
                    <h4>Product A</h4>
                    <a href="#" class="enrolLink">ABCDEFGHig</a>
                    <div class="info">product info1<br>Product Info 2 <br> Product info 3</div>
                </div>

                <!-- *********Second course******** -->
                <div class="col-md-3 courses">
                    <h5>ABCDEFGHig</h5>
                    <h4>Product B</h4>
                    <a href="#" class="enrolLink">ABCDEFGHig</a>
                    <div class="info">Product info 1<br>Product Info 2 <br> Product info 3</div>
               </div>

                <!-- *********Third course******** -->
                <div class="col-md-3 courses">
                    <h5>ABCDEFGHig</h5>
                    <h4>Product C</h4>
                    <a href="#" class="enrolLink">ABCDEFGHig</a>
                    <div class="info">Product info 1<br>Product Info 2 <br> Product info 3</div>
                </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Here is the fiddle for my code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lfqgq64p/

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Best Regards.

Comment: You can use 'hidden-xs' class to hide the part you want in extra small screen resolution

Comment: thanks for that  @AbhishekAgarwalla. I also want the content image and the content-title to come side-byside in mobile devices and the main-list to take up complete raw. But it is not happening right now.

Comment: you can do that by additionally adding 'col-xs-' property along with 'col-md-' property, One thing I wasn't able to understand is that why you are using all the col properties like 'col-sm', 'col-md', 'col-lg'

Comment: I am trying everything right now. in small devices, after hiding the featured image, I am not getting the titlle and sub title adjacent to the content image. It is coming below that image. And main list is not spreading to 12 columns in small devices. the small images are also messed up